# Excel formulas to track sales - count and extract functions

Tags: excel, formula

This is an example of a sales tracking spreadsheet that I want to create. 
I want column L to count the number of sales each person does but do it so that it runs in a fill series order. I have inputted data manually in column L to demonstrate.

there are approximately 11 different types of membership. As I enter the sales information in columns B to G, I want the types of membership in column G to extract to the breakdown box in columns P to T. This is so that I can see which staff member sells what types.

I want to replicate this formula to work out how much each staff member has taken financially. this would extract from H/I to the other box in column P to T.

[image]

Comment: Please use a [MCVE] and ask one question at a time.  Stack Overflow is not a place where one can come with a list of wants and have the volunteers here take of their personal time to do your work for you.

Comment: I appreciate that. I am just trying to learn and improve and have previously found this community helpful - thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer to the first part of your question:

> I want column L to count the number of sales each person does but do it so that it runs in a fill series order.

Formula for cell L1

```
=COUNTIF($K$1:K1;K1)
```

For L2 it then becomes

```
=COUNTIF($K$1:K2;K2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It does count, but doesn't seem to count in a fill series. I will work around with that formula - thanks.

Comment: I was not sure what you meant with 'count in a fill series'. For the second and third part of your question, I suggest that you create a pivot of your table.

Comment: So basically by count in a fill series, I mean that the first sale did would be automated as 1. The next time his name appears it is sale 2. Like a running total.

Comment: Think I have sussed it based in your original formula tweaked - thank you